# An example of a triply diminished interval in a specific piece of music

Tags: intervals

The thought spurred from a question I had for my music theory teacher. I asked her, “can doubly diminished intervals exist without double sharps or double flats?” We hadn’t gotten into double d or A, so we didn’t touch on it then, but I couldn’t stand it and had to figure it out right there so I drew a keyboard on my page and found an example, D# to Fb, 1 half step, a doubly diminished third with just single sharps or flats.
Since 4ths and 5ths are more easily diminished-funny statement-I realized you could make a triply diminished interval from just single sharps and flats, ie. **B# to Fb**. 4 half steps and a triply diminished 5th. So where could we see an example of this in a piece of music. Maybe a chromatic scale? The only 4 keys with B# or F# respectively would be those with 7 sharps or flats, namely, C#M, CbM, A#m, and Abm. I tried to look at these keys and see a modal use case or maybe harmonic/melodic minor use case:
To get both pitches B# and Fb occurring together, if you look at each scale in the aforementioned order (see pics), you would be flatting scale degree 4 in a major key(C#M), sharping scale degree 7 in a major key(CbM), flatting scale degree 2 and in a minor key(A#m), or sharping scale degree 2 in a minor key(Abm).
The only use case I could see is if you had a chromatic scale somewhere. So…

1. Can you provide a use case that uses the aforementioned interval B# to Fb besides a chromatic scale?
2. Can you think of another case of a triply diminished interval that doesn’t use double sharps or double flats, maybe a fourth of some kind? Or a triply augmented interval of some sort w/o bb or x? Any triply modified interval of any size besides the example that doesn’t use double sharps or double flats.
3. Thirdly, can you provide any real piece of music where a triply diminished or triply anugmented interval of any sort is seen or used, regardless of double sharps or flats?

[image: C#M]

[image: CbM]

[image: A#m]

[image: Abm]

Comment: Answering 2. to myself. Bb to E#, triply augmented fourth. This maybe could have a use case beyond chromatic scale? ‍♂️. Fb to B#, triply augmented fourth. Any other examples?

Comment: The general question "do triply-diminishes intervals serve any practical purpose" might have been on-topic, but this is as written a *list question*, ie. "list pieces that exhibit X feature" and as such is off-topic. With an edit, this could be saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can't build a 7 note scale with a triply diminished interval smaller than a (triply diminished) fifth, without repeating notes. So you're left with a fifth (your example: B#-Fb), sixth (e.g. B#-Gbb) or seventh (e.g. B#-Abb).

Also, your triply diminished fifth B#-Fb is the only example limited to single accidental, as B-F is the only diminished interval found on the white keys.

Scales including the notes B# and Fb are similar to:

**A** B# C# D Eb Fb **G**

with some combinations where the notes G and A can be moved in the range between Gbb and Ax. None of the combinations include any triads (diminished, minor, major or augmented). You could build A7b5 chord out of these notes, which is not extremely exotic, but I don't know how would you explain adding Fb (rather than E) in it.

Scales including B# and Gbb are similar to:

**A** B# C# D Eb Fb Gbb

with A movable in the range between Abbb to Ax. In any case, no triads can be found.

Finally,  scales with notes B# and Abb are

Abb B# **C# D Eb Fb Gbb**

You have half step of freedom between C# and Gb, but no combination gives you any triad.

To summarize, I don't see any reasonable way to have a triply diminished interval without enharmonic respelling.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question:

> Can you think of another case of a triply diminished interval that doesn’t use double sharps or double flats, maybe a fourth of some kind? Or a triply augmented interval of some sort w/o bb or x? Any triply modified interval of any size besides the example that doesn’t use double sharps or double flats.

If you move beyond 12-TET into alternative tunings, you'll get some very interesting results.

In 19-TET, for example, the triply-diminished fifth is enharmonically equivalent to the perfect fourth, and the triply-diminished fourth is equivalent to the minor third. In 31-TET, the triply-diminished fifth is equivalent to the augmented third, and the triply-diminished fourth is equivalent to the augmented second.